# Bash script: cd No such file or directory when file exists

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cd

My bash script is written to go to each subfolder in the current directory:

```
for d in */; 
do
    target=${d%/}
    cd "$target"
done
```

When I run my bash script, I am getting a cd error for a directory that exists:

```
++ for d in '*/'
++ target='Zelkova serrata'
++ cd 'Zelkova serrata'
./script7.sh: line 8: cd: Zelkova serrata: No such file or directory
```

Yet, in terminal command line I can do `cd 'Zelkova serrata'` within the same directory as the script and all is fine. Is it possible the bash script has a different source directory than the one its located in?

Comment: When using Linux, I would tend to avoid, where possible, file and directory names with spaces in them.  CamelCase or under_score is almost as easy to read, more common and much safer.

Comment: @Paul: absolutely agreed! Unfortunately, I didn't design its structure as I'm inheriting the code

Comment: Add `pwd` before `cd $target` and see if this reveals anything interesting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping through relative paths, try including the absolute path, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

pwd=$PWD
for d in */; 
do
    target="$pwd/${d%/}"
    cd "$target"
    echo $PWD
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the current directory is "state" that is modified on each pass of the loop and to use the posted commands, the cwd state should not be changed by a pass.

Spawning a subshell can fix this problem of mutating state.  The subshell inherits the state of its parent, but does not affect the parent.

`do ( command; command ; ...; )` will spawn a new shell on each loop pass.

```
for d in */; 
do (
  target=${d%/}
  cd "$target"
) done
```

Answer (score 0):

With bullet proofing

```
~$ find /full/path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -type d -printo | xargs -0 -I% sh -c "cd %; echo "do some fun here""
```

You'll escape name splitting if there is any space there.

Comment: `-printo` should be `-print0`, but really, just use `-exec` instead: `find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "$1" || exit ; echo "Do some fun in $PWD"' _ {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's happening, try this and examine the output carefully:

```
mkdir -p A/B/C B C D

echo Trying sequence: */
pwd
for d in */ ; do
    cd "$d"
    pwd
done
```

Perhaps what you want is:

```
mkdir -p A/B/C B C D

exec 3<. ; orig_dir=/proc/$$/fd/3

echo Trying sequence: */
pwd
for d in */ ; do
    cd -P "$orig_dir/$d"
    pwd
done
cd -P "$orig_dir"
pwd
```

or if `exec 3<.` does not work in your shell:

```
mkdir -p A/B/C B C D

orig_dir=$PWD

echo Trying sequence: */
pwd
for d in */ ; do
    cd -P "$orig_dir/$d"
    pwd
done
cd -P "$orig_dir"
pwd
```